# Is an XSS exploit possible when injected code is output inside quoted html attributes

Tags: javascript, security, xss

If I have a piece of HTML like so:

```
<div class=“feature-some-id”>
```

and `some-id` portion of the class has originated from user input via a query param, and that query param has not been escaped on the sever I am able to do this:

```
<div class=“feature-some-id</script>”>
```

The html is output via an express app like so:

```
res.render('my-template', {
  classNameSuffix: req.params.id
});
```

so it's raw user input.

Is there any way an attacker can break out of that script so that a script could be executed?

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd post the code that "protects" that user-originated content when the class name is formulated.

Comment: Why does that help? It's irrelevant to the question. I just want to know if that scenario had occurred is there any way an attacker could turn it in to an attack.

Comment: It helps because there are *countless* ways your code could assemble that HTML. Some might be vulnerable, some might not.

Comment: @Pointy updated the question. Short story is there is no protection so if the params contain malicious code it gets output as it was input without any escaping of any special chars.

Comment: Uhh OK. Why would you do that?

Comment: Well I haven't done it. I've inherited a codebase where this is happening.

Comment: Ah OK well that's a horse of a different color :)

Comment: Maybe the following could work (not sure what quirks mode of all browsers is) `/><img src='nope' onError=.'...` or `</div>...` If the user can only set that value for himself then there is no problem. It becomes dangerous when other users get html injected (no point in stealing your own cookies).

Comment: The above won’t work because they’d still be output insidd the quotes. It is also dangerous if the user can only set it for himself also. If I can socially engineer an attack where I can get a user to click on the link from an email with malcicious code in it for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can pass in a quote as part of the query param

```
?id=some-id"><script>alert()</script>
```

and have it end up, unescaped, in `req.params.id`, then you would get

```
<div class="feature-some-id"><script>alert()</script>
```

which obviously you could change `alert()` for any code you wanted to execute.

Comment: That actually gives me <div class="feature-some-id&quot;><script>alert()</script>"> so the double quote is being escaped. Wondering if there is any other way this could still be exploited